# $\min(\max(a,d),\max(b,d),\max(c,d))= \max (\min (a,b,c), d)$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have an easy question, but I need to check it.

$a$, $b$, $c$, $d$ are real positive numbers

Is $\min(\max(a,d),\max(b,d),\max(c,d))= \max (\min (a,b,c), d)$?

Comment: Hint: Split into cases.

Comment: The identity$$(a\vee d)\wedge(b\vee d)\wedge(c\vee d)=(a\wedge b\wedge c)\vee d$$ holds in any distributive lattece. Any totally ordered set (such as $\mathbb R$) is a distributive lattice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wolog $a \le b \le c$.

$\min(a,b,c) = a$.

$\max(\min(a,b,c),d)= \max(a,d) = a$ if $d \le a$

$\max(\min(a,b,c),d)= \max(a,d) = d$ if $d \ge a$.

If $d \le a$ then $\min(\max(a,d),\max(b,d),\max(c,d)) = \min(a,b,c) = a =  \max(\min(a,b,c),d)$

If $d \ge a$ then $\min(\max(a,d),\max(b,d),\max(c,d)) = \min(d, \max(b,d), \max(c,d)) = \min(d, d|b > d, d|c > d) = d = \max(\min(a,b,c),d)$.

So, yep, it's true.

Answer (score 2):

If $d$ is the maximum of the $4$ numbers we are done, as the left-hand side and right-hand side equal $d$. The expression is symmetric in $a, b, c$, so without loss of generality, we can assume $a\leq b\leq c$. There are $3$ more cases to consider.

1. $a\leq b\leq d\leq c$, in this case, the left-hand side and right-hand side equal $d$.
2. $a\leq d\leq b\leq c$, in this case, the left-hand side and right-hand side equal $d$.
3. $d\leq a\leq b\leq c$, in this case, the left-hand side and right-hand side equal $a$.